# I don't know how to solve this

Tags: c

After receiving the k value from the user, find the largest value and the n value at that time without (1+2+3+…+n) exceeding k.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Since I am Korean, I don't speak English well, so I don't know how to ask questions, so I only wrote the main subject. sorry..

Comment: eg: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-triangular-number-larger-than-p/

Comment: Hint: `1+2+3+...+n` is the same as `(n * (n + 1)) / 2`

Comment: did the replies above answer your question ? as it's not clear enough ..

Comment: If this is a math question, this is the wrong site.  If this is a coding problem you need to either explain what the code is required to do, and/or provide the code or your attempt or version.  It may be possible to determine what you need here but it is by no means clear or unambiguous.  The picture adds nothing.

Comment: I understand that you are Korean, but you can use Google translate to post your question. How am I supposed to help you without being able to understand your problem?

Comment: @risingStark probably by using Google Translate yourself in your comment?

Comment: @S.Ramjit No, the site rules require the OP to translate this themselves. Reviewers in the Suggested Edits queue don't necessarily know whether the translation is accurate and we don't know whether the OP would understand it. We can't accept edits that might introduce these problems. Also, many reviewers would require the OP to transcribe an image even if was in English anyway due to the risk of introducing errors.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I solve this?

One way is to just compare the new sum to *k* before incrementing *n* and adding it to the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned k, l, n;
    while (printf("k .. .....: "), scanf("%u", &k) > 0 && k != -1u)
    {
        for (l = 0, n = 0; l+n < k; l += ++n) ;
        printf("1.. %d... .. %d....\n", n, l);
    }
}
```